# Org agenda view with multiple headers

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to create a `org-mode` agenda dashboard that has multiple headers, each with content from a different query. How can I make this happen with a single command? Am I forced to have them in separate buffers?

Answer (score 2):

The variable `org-agenda-custom-commands` can contain search parameters for multiple blocks that have different search criteria.  Here is a section from the Emacs manual:

```
10.6.2 Block agenda

Another possibility is the construction of agenda views that comprise
the results of several commands, each of which creates a block in the
agenda buffer. The available commands include agenda for the daily or
weekly agenda (as created with C-c a a), alltodo for the global TODO
list (as constructed with C-c a t), and the matching commands discussed
above: todo, tags, and tags-todo. Here are two examples:

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("h" "Agenda and Home-related tasks"
         ((agenda "")
          (tags-todo "home")
          (tags "garden")))
        ("o" "Agenda and Office-related tasks"
         ((agenda "")
          (tags-todo "work")
          (tags "office")))))

This will define C-c a h to create a multi-block view for stuff you
need to attend to at home. The resulting agenda buffer will contain
your agenda for the current week, all TODO items that carry the tag
‘home’, and also all lines tagged with ‘garden’. Finally the command
C-c a o provides a similar view for office tasks.
```

---

See also the `org-mode` manual at the section entitled *Custom Agenda Commands*:

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html